Can't make application commands sync
I wish to organize the commands as I plan to add many. I'm struggling to make the cog files load. I watched a bunch of tutorials for the application commands step by step. When the bot runs, the commands: ratio, castle_cost and ta_cost should be visible as a slash command in discord while in a cog.
main.py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

import locale
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pytz

# Load environment variables from the .env file
load_dotenv()

# Set up Discord intents
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)


# Event handler for when the bot is ready
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {bot.user}')
    await bot.tree.sync()  # Sync application commands globally
    print("Application commands synced globally.")
    await bot.load_extension('cogs.calculations')



# Set the timezone for CST
cst = pytz.timezone('America/Chicago')

# Define the reset intervals
colonies_reset_interval = timedelta(days=10)
hell_mode_reset_interval = timedelta(days=7)
guild_reset_interval = timedelta(days=5)

# Set the last reset times in CST
colonies_last_reset_time = cst.localize(datetime(2024, 4, 20, 9, 55))  # Initial reset time
hell_mode_last_reset_time = cst.localize(datetime(2024, 4, 21, 9, 50))  # Initial reset time
guild_last_reset_time = cst.localize(datetime(2024, 4, 25, 9, 55))  # Initial reset time

# Command to show the time until the next reset for various events
@bot.tree.command(name="reset", description="Shows the time until the next reset for various events")
async def reset(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    now = datetime.now(cst)  # Get the current time in CST
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Time Until Next Reset", color=discord.Color.red())

    # Calculate the time until the next reset
    colonies_next_reset = calculate_next_reset(now, colonies_last_reset_time, colonies_reset_interval)
    hell_mode_next_reset = calculate_next_reset(now, hell_mode_last_reset_time, hell_mode_reset_interval)
    guild_next_reset = calculate_next_reset(now, guild_last_reset_time, guild_reset_interval)

    # Format the time until the next reset
    colonies_formatted = format_time_remaining(colonies_next_reset - now)
    hell_mode_formatted = format_time_remaining(hell_mode_next_reset - now)
    guild_formatted = format_time_remaining(guild_next_reset - now)

    # Add fields to the embed with Discord timestamps
    embed.add_field(name="Colonies Reset", value=f"<t:{int(colonies_last_reset_time.timestamp())}:F> {colonies_formatted}", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Hell Mode Reset", value=f"<t:{int(hell_mode_last_reset_time.timestamp())}:F> {hell_mode_formatted}", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Guild Reset", value=f"<t:{int(guild_last_reset_time.timestamp())}:F> {guild_formatted}", inline=False)

    await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)

# Helper function to calculate the time elapsed since the last reset
def calculate_time_elapsed(now, last_reset_time, reset_interval):
    time_since_last_reset = now - last_reset_time
    resets_since_last = time_since_last_reset // reset_interval
    time_elapsed = time_since_last_reset - (resets_since_last * reset_interval)
    return time_elapsed

# Helper function to format the time elapsed
def format_time_elapsed(time_elapsed):
    hours, remainder = divmod(time_elapsed.seconds, 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
    return f"{hours:02d}:{minutes:02d} PM" if hours < 12 else f"{hours-12:02d}:{minutes:02d} AM"

# Helper function to calculate the time until the next reset
def calculate_next_reset(now, last_reset_time, reset_interval):
    time_since_last_reset = now - last_reset_time
    resets_since_last = time_since_last_reset // reset_interval
    next_reset_time = last_reset_time + (resets_since_last + 1) * reset_interval
    return next_reset_time

# Helper function to format the time remaining until the next reset
def format_time_remaining(time_remaining):
    days = time_remaining.days
    hours, remainder = divmod(time_remaining.seconds, 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
    return f"{days} Days, {hours} Hours, {minutes} Minutes"
    


@bot.tree.command(name="sync", description="Sync the application commands")
async def sync(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    print(f'Syncing for {interaction.guild.name}')
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"Syncing application commands...", ephemeral=True)
    synced = await bot.tree.sync(guild=interaction.guild)
    await interaction.edit_original_response(content=f"Synced {len(synced)} commands.")


bot.run(os.getenv('Discord_Token'))

calculations.py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import app_commands
from typing import Optional
import locale

class calculationsCog(commands.Cog, name="calculations"):
    """A collection of utility commands."""

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @app_commands.command(name="ratio", description="finds a hero to wave ratio")
    async def ratio(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, hero: int, wave: int):
        if hero <= 0 or wave <= 0:
            await interaction.response.send_message("Hero and wave values must be positive integers.", ephemeral=True)
            return

        hero_ratio = hero / wave
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Hero to Wave Ratio", color=discord.Color.red())
        embed.add_field(name="Ratio", value=f"{hero_ratio:.2f}")
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)

    @app_commands.command(name="castle_cost", description="finds the gold cost of one castle level to another")
    @app_commands.describe(
        castle_level="The current castle level",
        castle_target_level="The desired castle level"
    )
    async def castle_cost(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, castle_level: int, castle_target_level: int):
        if castle_level <= 0 or castle_target_level <= 0 or castle_level > castle_target_level:
            await interaction.response.send_message("Castle levels must be positive integers, and the target level must be higher than the current level.", ephemeral=True)
            return

        castle_gold_cost = (castle_level + castle_target_level) * (castle_target_level - castle_level + 1) * 2500 // 2
        formatted_cost = format_number(castle_gold_cost)
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Castle Upgrade Cost", color=discord.Color.red())
        embed.add_field(name="Cost", value=formatted_cost)
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)

    @app_commands.command(name="ta_cost", description="finds the gold cost of one ta level to another")
    @app_commands.describe(
        ta_level="The current TA level",
        ta_target_level="The desired TA level"
    )
    async def ta_cost(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, ta_level: int, ta_target_level: int):
        if ta_level <= 0 or ta_target_level <= 0 or ta_level > ta_target_level:
            await interaction.response.send_message("TA levels must be positive integers, and the target level must be higher than the current level.", ephemeral=True)
            return

        ta_level_cost = (0.5 * ((ta_level * 1000) * ta_level)) - (44500 * ta_level)
        ta_target_cost = (0.5 * ((ta_target_level * 1000) * ta_target_level)) - (44500 * ta_target_level)
        ta_gold_cost = ta_target_cost - ta_level_cost
        formatted_cost = format_number(ta_gold_cost)
        embed = discord.Embed(title="TA Upgrade Cost", color=discord.Color.red())
        embed.add_field(name="Cost", value=formatted_cost)
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)

def format_number(number):
    # Set the locale for formatting numbers with commas
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
    formatted_number = locale.format_string('%d', number, grouping=True)
    if number >= 1000000000000:
        # Format numbers with 'T' suffix for trillions
        suffix = f" ({locale.format_string('%0.2fT', number / 1000000000000, grouping=True)} gold)"
    elif number >= 1000000000:
        # Format numbers with 'B' suffix for billions
        suffix = f" ({locale.format_string('%0.2fB', number / 1000000000, grouping=True)} gold)"
    elif number >= 1000000:
        # Format numbers with 'M' suffix for millions
        suffix = f" ({locale.format_string('%0.2fM', number / 1000000, grouping=True)} gold)"
    else:
        # No suffix for smaller numbers
        suffix = ""
    return formatted_number + suffix

async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(calculationsCog(bot))


I noticed an inconsistency in this function. You are syncing your commands before loading Cog, which means existing commands in Cog are never synced. Test synchronize the commands after loading the cog.
# Wrong
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {bot.user}')
    await bot.tree.sync()  # Sync application commands globally
    print("Application commands synced globally.")
    await bot.load_extension('cogs.calculations')

# Correct
async def on_ready():
    await bot.load_extension('cogs.calculations')
    print(f'We have logged in as {bot.user}')
    await bot.tree.sync()  # Sync application commands globally
    print("Application commands synced globally.")

